# Accesing Json data after 'loading' it

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

With a lot of help from people in this site, I managed to get some Json data from an amazon page. The data, for example, looks like this.

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=9ea92643044f4ac88bcc3e76d98425fc

First I have a list of strings which is converted to a string.

```
script = response.xpath('//script/text()').extract()
#For example, I need the variationValues data
variationValues = re.findall(r'variationValues\" : ({.*?})', ' '.join(script))[0]
```

Then, in my code, I have this (not a great name, will be changed later)

```
variationValuesJson = json.loads(variationValues)
```

variationValuesJson is in fact a dictionary, so doing something like this

```
variationValues["size_name"][3]
```

Should return "5.5 M US"

My issue is that, when running the program, I get the string indices must be integers error. Anyone knows whats wrong?

Note: I have tried using 'size_name' instead of "size_name", same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
variationValues["size_name"][3]    #this is the raw string which you have converted to variationValuesjson
```

I think this is not what you actually want.

Your code should be this.

```
variationValuesJson['size_name'][3]    #use variationValuesjson ;)
```